# Is there any way limit the form of the query in graphql

Tags: graphql

For example, if there are two types User and Item

```
type User {
  items: [Item!]!
}

type Item {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  price: Int!
}
```

If one user has PARTNER role.
I want to prevent it from being called only in the form of the query below.

```
query Query1 {
   user {
     items {
       name
     }
   }
}
```

If user call another query, I want to indicate that user doesn't have permission.

```
query Query2 {
   user {
     items {
       id
       name
     }
   }
}
```

In short. if (Query1 != Query2) throw new Error;

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit hard to follow but a couple things:

1. A GraphQL server is *stateless* - you cannot (and really should not) have a query behave differently based on a previous query. (If there's a mutation in between sure but not two queries back to back)
2. access management is normally implemented in your resolvers. You can have the resolver for the item `id` check to see if the user making the query has the right to see that or not and return an error if they don't have access.

Note that it can be bad practice to hide the `id` of objects from queries as these are used as keys for caching on the client.